# Cannot Access Memory at Address - RISCV gdb/Linux no KSLR

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, qemu, riscv

I'm working on a custom Linux kernel for a RISC-V architecture. I am debugging using GDB/QEMU now that those tools are available. As I am debugging I notice that I am not able to access memory at addresses that are virtualized. That is once memory gets transitioned from physical to virtual addressing in the kernel, I can't access those memory locations any longer in gdb. For example, the kernel shows up like this in QEMU's `info mem` command.

```
paddr: 0x80200000 --> vaddr: 0xffffffff80000000
```

I think this question/problem is more an issue with QEMU or maybe my understanding of how to access it in QEMU correctly. As it stands, single stepping to this point in my kernel where virtual memory starts being used is fine but single stepping beyond this causes QEMU to effectively stop--it gives the same instruction each step. However, if I continue it boots in QEMU. How can I debug this via single stepping? Is there something I need to switch in GDB/QEMU?

I did try to access an address 0xffffffff8000007c for example and I could get that successfully, QEMU just doesn't transition to virtual memory when I single step past that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar problem and have formed the following hypothesis:
I think the kernel is switching to a reduced page table when in idle,
one that does not map loaded module memory.  An asynchronous break by GDB has a high likelihood of interrupting the CPU while in idle, of course.

Single stepping out idle (e.g., after hitting a key in the Linux console) and re-attempting setting a breakpoint on the loaded module succeeds at some point.

A viable strategy is probably to break on the conclusion of the module loading code and to set relevant breakpoints at that point.